# Edittext become squeeze in BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, keyboard-events, bottom-sheet

I have a **BottomSheetDialogFragment** in which simple layout file
with edittext at the bottom and recyclerview on top, when the user
taps on edittext and soft keyboard opens and write few lines in
edittext and try to scroll it, during scrolling if i tap on any line
edittext squeezes itself and also **BottomSheetDialogFragment** jerks
like it is rendering itself.

Here is my Code

**layout_file:**

```
<RelativeLayout
   android:id="@+id/layout"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="@color/background"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   app:behavior_hideable="true"
   app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
   <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/etPostShare">
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
             android:id="@+id/rvNewMessage"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

   </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
   <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etPostShare"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:hint="Aa"
        android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        android:maxHeight="60dp"
        android:maxLength="@integer/send_chat_txt_limit"
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:paddingLeft="18.4dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:textSize="14.6sp" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Here i attached a images and also video link of my issue:

[image]

**https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bADuzDQoWep8XPMQ4ypKCWJyD32Gtfwp/view?usp=sharing**

Comment: Please try to make your recycler view height wrap content

Comment: let me know it helps you or not.

Comment: Its not working @AbhishekBhardwaj

Comment: swiperefreshlayout and recylerview both should have wrap_content for height property

Comment: Thats not work because of that button should be shown on bottom and recyclerview must be on top of button @Jileshl

Answer (score 2):

I have the exact same problem. Hope it's working :)

style.xml

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item> 
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
</style>
```

in your BottomSheetDialogFragment

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.DialogStyle)
}
```

in your layout

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:gravity="bottom"
   android:orientation="vertical">

           .... your content with EditText



  </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works in preview

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:behavior_hideable="true"
            app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

            <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
                android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/rvNewMessage"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

            </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPostShare"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:background="@null"
                android:gravity="center|left"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:hint="Aa\naa"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
                android:isScrollContainer="true"
                android:maxHeight="60dp"
                android:maxLength="500"
                android:maxLines="4"
                android:paddingLeft="18.4dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:textSize="14.6sp" />

        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I tried your solution, but it is again squeezing while scrolling in edittext and then user tap on editing any specific character in edittext.

Comment: The same above XML works for me; I can see Edittext floating above the Recyclerview with max 4 lines @AsadMukhtar

Comment: I know its above but i think you didn`t read the question carefully because of that in Bottom sheet dialog behavior edittext squeezes.

Comment: Got it; the solution above I tried to run it in my project with layout behavior as bottomsheetbehavior and it isn't shrinking the edittext; Tested it on Android 6;

Reason it works is because; SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't depend on Edittext for its position (your XML does say that 
** android:layout_above="@+id/etPostShare"
While the above solution uses relative layout config to float in the bottom